# Using 'expect' command to pass password to SSH running script remotely

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, expect

I need to create a bash script that will remotely run another script on a batch of machines.  To do so I am passing a script through SSH.

```
ssh -p$port root@$ip 'bash -s' < /path/to/script/test.sh
```

I thought it would use my RSA keys but I am getting error:

```
"Enter password: ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"
```

I tried using sshpass to no avail.  So my next solution was using expect. I have never used expect before and I'm positive my syntax is way off.

```
ssh -p$port root@$ip 'bash -s' < /path/to/script/test.sh
/usr/bin/expect <<EOD
expect "password"
send "$spass\n"
send "\n"
EOD
```

I have root access to all machines and ANY solution will do as long as the code remains within bash.  Just keep in mind that this will be done in a loop with global variables ($spass, $ip, $port, etc) passed from a parent script.

Comment: Is your SSH public key in each of the machines' root's `.ssh/authorized_keys` file? I would think the best case scenario to shoot for here is to figure out why you are getting the smackdown when trying to do your ssh auth using a keypair.

Comment: You can try connecting manually with `ssh -v {port} root@{ip}` to get a better picture of what's going on.

Comment: Fixing the key issue is a **much** better solution than hacking around the password prompting.

Comment: @Jnevill and Etan I agree on both accounts. SSH works every where else except here and I can not for the  life of me figure out why.   Mike thanks for the tip. I'll have to try it when I get to work tomorrow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are doing it wrong in two means:

1. If you want `expect` to interact with `ssh`, you need to start `ssh` from `expect` script and not before.
2. If you put the script (`/path/to/script/test.sh`) to `stdin` of `ssh`, you can't communicate with the `ssh` process any more.

You should rather copy the script to remote host using scp and then run it.

Expect script might look like this:

```
/usr/bin/expect <<EOF
spawn ssh -p$port root@$ip
expect "password"
send "$Spass\r"
expect "$ "
send "/path/to/script/on/remote/server/test.sh\r"
expect "$ "
interact
EOF
```

Comment: missing `interact` and `EOF`

Comment: @szpal Thanks. Fixed now.

Comment: Thanks, that certainly did the trick.  Is there a way to make it wait for the other script to finish before it moves on?  I usually use `source`, will that play nice with expect?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean. I would consult with manual page, understand what this code snippet do and then try to compose another question, if there will be something unclear.

Answer (score 0):

```
    #!/usr/bin/expect
    #Replace with remote username and remote ipaddress
    spawn /usr/bin/ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no username@IPAddress
    #Replace with remote username and remote ipaddress
    expect "username@IPAddress's password: "
    #Provide remote system password
    send "urpassword\n"
    #add commands to be executed. Also possible to execute bash scripts
    expect "$ " {send "pwd\n"} # bash command
    expect "$ " {send "cd mytest\n"}
    expect "$ " {send "./first.sh\n"} # bash scripts
    expect "$ " {send "exit\n"}
    interact
```

Comment: Please provide description of your answer

Comment: Expect tool can be used for automating interactive applications such as ssh,telnet, ftp, passwd, fsck, rlogin, tip, etc.
Try some examples from below url.
http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/10/expect-examples